# Unable to connect to mysql via php but works fine from command line

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I am just setting up a new VPS learning to setup my own web server and stuck at this pretty basic step.

```
PHP 5.3.3
MySQL 5.1.61
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
```

I can connect to the server using mysql at the command line or remotely using Navicat without issues. I've put the host as '%' for testing as localhost wouldn't work either. I have tried with "localhost", IP, etc.

```
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'stats'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Users:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Host      | User    |
+-----------+---------+
| %         | stats   |
| 127.0.0.1 | root    |
| localhost | root    |
+-----------+---------+
```

My code:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "db", "pw");
?>
```

Error when running the php script directly from the command line (No web server):

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'stats'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /xxx/db.php on line 5
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'stats'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The same is returned when running through apache.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your data base and your php code on the same server?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm using "localhost" to connect, thanks for helping clarifying that!

Comment: I asked that because it is a common mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "db", "pw");
```

Should be:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pw", "db");
```

password comes before database name

Comment: Winner, wow. It proves that a second pair of eyes sometimes can fix the easiest of problems!

Comment: Oh I was going to.. I was constantly checking if I can click the checkmark! You answered too fast. :D

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

**Edit**

Check the permissions for the user you are trying to connect the db with.

Comment: The mysqli extension is an improved mysql extension for mysql 4.1+, I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the problem. I'm not getting an error with the extension, I'm getting a user access denied error.

Comment: then you should check for the permissions for the username u r using

Answer (score -1):

Have you entered correct password? Check password

Comment: The password is correct, as stated above I can login using the command line or remote access.